# Updating objects within Nested Array in mongodb with multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, mongodb

An example document in mongo looks as follows however my collection has a couple of thousand documents, where some have all of the following tests, and some have only a subset of the following tests:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52435f0f6f73205f7d37a2b0"),
"ID" : {
    "schoolID" : "1234"
},
"institution" : {
    "tests" : [
        {
            "test" : "SAT Math",
            "25th_percentile" : null,
            "mean" : 404,
            "50th_percentile" : null,
            "75th_percentile" : null
        },
        {
            "test" : "SAT Verbal",
            "25th_percentile" : null,
            "mean" : 355,
            "50th_percentile" : null,
            "75th_percentile" : null
        },
        {
            "test" : "SAT Writing",
            "25th_percentile" : null,
            "mean" : 363,
            "50th_percentile" : null,
            "75th_percentile" : null
        },
        {
            "test" : "SAT Composite",
            "25th_percentile" : null,
            "mean" : 1122,
            "50th_percentile" : null,
            "75th_percentile" : null
        },
        {
            "test" : "ACT Math",
            "25th_percentile" : null,
            "mean" : null,
            "50th_percentile" : null,
            "75th_percentile" : null
        },
        {
            "test" : "ACT English",
            "25th_percentile" : null,
            "mean" : null,
            "50th_percentile" : null,
            "75th_percentile" : null
        },
        {
            "test" : "ACT Reading",
            "25th_percentile" : null,
            "mean" : null,
            "50th_percentile" : null,
            "75th_percentile" : null
        },
        {
            "test" : "ACT Science",
            "25th_percentile" : null,
            "mean" : null,
            "50th_percentile" : null,
            "75th_percentile" : null
        },
        {
            "test" : "ACT Composite",
            "25th_percentile" : null,
            "mean" : null,
            "50th_percentile" : null,
            "75th_percentile" : null
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I have currently received separate data for a couple of schools and want to update the document where ID is "schoolID" and where "test" is "ACT Composite" and "mean" is null.

I have tried the following:

```
db.collection.update({$and:[{"ID.schoolID":"1234"},    {"institution.tests.$.test": "ACT Composite"}, {"institution.tests.$.mean": null}]}, {"$set":{"institution.tests.$.mean":"trial"}})
```

however, the object was not updated. 
I have also tried using $elemMatch:

```
db.collection.update({$and:[{"ID.schoolID":"1234"},{"institution.tests": {$elemMatch:{"test": "ACT Composite", "mean":null}}}]},{"institution.tests.$.mean":"trial"})
```

when using $elemMatch I was able to get a count of the number of documents where this is true:

```
db.collection.find({"institution.tests":{$elemMatch:{"test":"ACT Composite", "mean":null}}}).count()
```

Lastly, I have also tried writing a python script using pymongo which turns the object into a pandas dataframe ( as I am more familiar as to how to do this in R using a dataframe and an "ifelse", however, I was having trouble only updating the specific object where "test" is "ACT Composite" and "mean" is null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
db.collection.update(
  {
    "ID.schoolID": "1234",
    "institution.tests": { $elemMatch: { test: "ACT Composite", mean: null } },
  },
  { $set: { "institution.tests.$.mean": "trial" } }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!! unfortunately, that did not update the document :( Instead it updated where "test": "ACT Math"

Comment: I have updated query. Could you please try it again.